# Unable to download docker image layer from JFrog Artifactory using curl

Tags: artifactory

I am using the command:

```bash
curl -O -u username:API_KEY https://artifactory_url/artifactory/docker_repo/image/tag/sha
```

The file created after curl completes successfully is empty

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen if [redirect download feature](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Direct+Cloud+Storage+Download) is enabled on Artifactory side. The reason is, when a repository is configured to redirect downloads, a client requesting Artifactory for an artifact(exceeding a specific file size) hosted in that repository receives a 302 response initially with a Location header containing a signed direct download url. Then the client uses the particular URL to download the actual file.

Hence we would need to make sure follow redirect option is enabled by the client attempting to download it. In case of curl it can be achieved by adding `-L`

> curl -O -L -u username:API_KEY
> https://artifactory_url/artifactory/docker_repo/image/tag/sha